# Place datalayer.push code in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Being new to GTM. My question might be very lame.
 I have following query in regards to datalayer.push code/method/function
If i want to place datalayer.push code/method/function on web pages were should i place the code on the page
1) should it be above GTM code 
2) should it be below the GTM code 
3) should I place it were I declare/define the datalayer

Also, would like to know if there are rules that need to be followed while placing the datalayer.push code/method/function on the pages
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Some best practices regarding the dataLayer including defining the initial dataLayer BEFORE the GTM container:

```
<body>
   <script>
      dataLayer = [{
         'event': 'someEvent',
         // other parameters
      }]
   </script>

   <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
   ...
   <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

and if you want to do a dataLayer.push, then that also should come before the container.

```
<body>
   <script>
      dataLayer = [{
         'event': 'someEvent',
         // other parameters
      }]
   </script>

   <script>
      dataLayer.push({
         'category': 'clothing',
         // other additional parameters
      })
   </script>

   <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
   ...
   <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

In some cases, you may want to check to see if the data layer object has been defined or not first, before pushing to it:

```
window['dataLayer'] = window['dataLayer'] || []
dataLayer.push({
   'newVar': 'newValue'
})
```

Comment: Thanks Nyuen for your guidance. What difference does it make if I  place datalayer.push code above or below the GTM snippet. Does it affect the data collection into GA.

Comment: If you place data layer code below the container, then GTM won't be able to use any of the data because the container would have already loaded.

Comment: Good but is there any complete instruction to set up tagmanager and analytics to use userID and show its report? - thanks this will be very helpful in the future.